# как вывести пользователей с возрастом > 55 , не имея в таблице колонки возраста?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте!
перед мной стоит такая вот задача : "вывести имена, фамилии, возраст работодателей чей возраст больше 55 и отсортировать по фамилии"
так как колонки с возрастом у меня нет, я применил функцию `DATEDIFF` и у меня получился следующий код :

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, DATEDIFF(YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
CASE
WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDate,GETDATE()),Birthdate)
> GETDATE() THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END AS [age] FROM Employees
```

собственно этот запрос выводит мне фамилию, имя и возрасты работодателей(в отдельном столбце), но как мне вывести только тех кто старше 55? Когда я пишу `WHERE age > 55`, Managment Studio говорит мне, что `age` не верное имя столбца?
Прошу вашей помощи уважаемые программисты !

Comment: конечно говорит. у вас `age` это  алиас, а их нельзя использовать в условиях. Либо сделайте CTE/подзапрос и отфильтруйте по `age`, либо повторите все ваше выражение вычисления возраста целиком в `where`

Comment: проверяйте явно дату рождения в условии. `where BirthDate <= dateadd(YY,-55,getdate())`

Comment: @Mike ГЕ-НИ-АЛЬ-Но , спасибо огромное! ломал голову около недели, а все оказалось так просто !

Comment: @Mike оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алиасы, объявляемые в списке выборки `[age]` нельзя использовать в условиях того же уровня запроса, там они не доступны. Необходимо целиком писать все вычисляемое выражение в условии или пойти другим путем, вычислив дату рождения для требуемого возраста.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname,
       DATEDIFF(YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
       CASE
       WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDate,GETDATE()),Birthdate) > GETDATE()
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [age]
 FROM Employees
WHERE BirthDate <= dateadd(YY,-55,getdate())
```

Comment: решение идеальное для меня!
скажите пожалуйста, а можно ли не создавая промежуточную таблицу вывести min, max, averege age ?

Comment: @DoneBass  `select min(age), max(age), avg(age) from ( запрос-который-выше ) X`

Comment: не выходит, говорит что не верное имя столбца

Comment: @DoneBass хм. должно выбирать, во внутреннем запросе же вот тот алиас [age] есть ? `select min(age), max(age), avg(age) from ( select ... [age] from Emploees where ...) X`

Comment: вы не могли бы написать как должен выглядеть запрос?
мне что то подсказует что я не правильно делаю.

Comment: @DoneBass Так я и написал, вместо ... подставьте формулу вычисления возраста и условие выборки

Comment: прошу прощения, не заметил

Comment: 'select min(age), max(age), avg(age) from (select city, firstname, lastname, DATEDIFF (YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
CASE
 WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()), birthdate)
 > GETDATE() THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END AS [age] 
from Employees) X where city='London'
'
c помощью этого запроса выводятся мин, макс, средн возраст работодателей из Лондона, а как сделать вывод этих же возрастов для всех городов?
извините что так много вопросов, но это очень важно для меня

Comment: @DoneBass Убираете условие по городу, добавляете `group by city`